# Switch between Javascript functions based on Checkbox or Toggle selection (Tableau API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle, tableau-api

I want to use a checkbox or toggle checkbox to switch between two Tableau Javascript API functions.

It get mixed results.  A single filter will ADD and REMOVE in a checkbox.  It will not work when applying multiple values to the filter (e.g., (filterName, [Value 1, Value 2], ADD)).

It will run the first action when "connected" to a checkbox toggle switch, but it will not switch back and return the other function.

```
function filterMainViz(filterName, values) {
    var sheet = mainViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    var updateType;
    if($('#'+values).is(":checked"))    {
        updateType = "ADD";
    } else {
        updateType = "REMOVE";
    }
    worksheetArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
        worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, updateType);
    }
}
```

Similar problem when I try to apply this approach to switch between two functions.  It will run the first action (check or toggle), but it will not switch back or run the second function.

```
function switchMainViz() {
    var sheet = mainViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    var updateType;
    if($('#').is(":checked"))    {
        chartPercent();
    } else {
        chartAmount();
    }
}
```

The original chartPerce() is

```
function chartPercent() {

    mainWorkbook = mainViz.getWorkbook();
    // Set to Detail to Percent
    mainWorkbook.changeParameterValueAsync("Amount or Percent", "Percent").then(function () {
        alertOrConsole("'Chart Type' parameter set to Percent");
    });
}
```

The original chartAmount() is

```
function chartAmount() {
    mainWorkbook = mainViz.getWorkbook();
    // Set to Detail to Amount
    mainWorkbook.changeParameterValueAsync("Amount or Percent", "Amount").then(function () {
        alertOrConsole("'Chart type' parameter set to Amount");
    });
}
```

Comment: I should stress I am a total Javascript noob.

Comment: in your ***switchMainViz()*** function id is missing in you code right here *** if($('#').is(":checked"))***   it should be ***if($('#'+yourCheckboxorRadiobuttonId).is(":checked"))***

Comment: Bingo, that was it.  **Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing Id in your jquery selector right here   `if($('#').is(":checked"))` in the function `switchMainViz()`

It should be like `if($('#'+YourId).is(":checked"));`